# Expected an identifier in Flutter ToDo App

Tags: flutter, dart, identifier

I'm currently following a tutorial of a ToDo-App in flutter. With the code of the "Checkbox"-Function (which is there to display whether you have finished a task or not), I get the following error:
Expected an identifier.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Check extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isActive;
  const Check({Key? key, this.isActive}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isActive ??){
      return Container(
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.check,
          size: 20,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Icon(Icons.check, size: 20, color: Colors.white),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Would really appreciate if you could support me on this. I'm mostly new to flutter and searched everywhere I could think of for how to solve this issue but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing an operand in your first condition

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isActive ?? false) {   <<< 
      return Container(
      ...
```

You can check this [nullable operators article](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb)

Comment: Tried it and it seems to work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second expression on line 9

```
if (isActive ?? false)
```

the ?? operator means If expr1 is non-null, returns its value; otherwise, evaluates and returns the value of expr2.

```
expr1 ?? expr2
```

Comment: I think it is necessary to turn the `bool?` into a non nullable type `bool` by doing the check

Comment: I tried to use the bool without the "?" but that didn't seem to work. Thank you very much for the explanation of the ?? operator! :)

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to make `isActive` not-nullable and provide it with a default value of `false`.

```dart
class Check extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isActive;

  const Check({
    Key? key, 
    this.isActive = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // ....
}

Avoid Nullable values when possible.
```